# Can I run AWS Lambda functions in my data center

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

AWS claims that it allows Lambda functions to be executed in devices via AWS GreenGrass. I was trying to understand whether we can execute the Lambda functions in other VMs in my data center too. But couldn't find any infromation on it. Please note this is not testing the Lambda functions locally. This is about doing the computing locally.

Comment: I would think you can do it with greengrass. When greengrass was announced, it rang a bell with me since I would have a need for it around 10 years ago when I was developing *intranet* systems for a school with almost no internet connection. I suggest you try it out and see if it works for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS Greengrass documentation it gives an example of setting up Greengrass on an EC2 instance which is a virtual machine...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module1.html#setup-filter.ec2

This is essentially the same as running it on a VM in your data centre. If you installed it on a Raspberry PI you could plug it into the network in your data centre and it could communicate with AWS IOT.

One thing you should do is to run the GG Dependency Checker on the OS that you want to try and run GG on...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module1.html#setup-filter.other

This can tell you what's missing for GG to run on your OS.

AWS also list supported OSes here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html#gg-platforms

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do the computation locally on the Greengrass VM.  If you are using devices to communicate with greengrass and lambda, make sure that you tell the devices not to sync to the cloud, but only the "local shadow service." For greater efficiency, make sure that the lambda is unpinned.  Also, you can modify the Greengrass lambda in the VM itself, restart the lambda and run using the new code.  Just be careful, because if you deploy again with modifications on the lambda, it may be over written.

Comment: @Amila-Maharachchi  If you have OpenStack, Hyper-V or any way of creating your own virtual machine. You can also deploy a standard Ubuntu instance and deploy Greengrass there as well with lambda running.  We do that.  If you have any specific questions, feel free.